# Select data between dashes from a table

Tags: php, mysqli

I hope somebody has any idea how to get data from a table using a query but just the characters between the dashes " - ". I cant use substr because is limited to a few characters. I have a few hours trying to figure out but i cant. Please help.

```
      Data
+-------------+
|   MYTABLE   |
+-------------+
|  PSL-9-1    |
|  PSL-9-2    |
|  PSL-10-1   |
|  PSL-10-2   |
|  PSL-500-1  |
|  PSL-8600-1 |
+-------------+

Desired output:

+-------------+
|   MYTABLE   |
+-------------+
|     9       |
|     9       |
|     10      |
|     10      |
|     500     |
|     8600    |
+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, you may be closer to the solution than you think and it helps us to provide a relevant answer

Comment: Do you want the answer to be pure MYSQL or can you do this in PHP

Comment: sounds like someone needs to redesign their db a little

Comment: Sounds like the data is in the DB incorrectly. "PSL" should be a column, then the bit between the hyphens another column, then the bit after the hyphens another column. then you can get them all, add hyphens if needed or get single specific data. Using delimiters to separate different data in one column is nearly always a bad thing to do. Can you refactor the DB or does it have to be like this?

Comment: @James Hi, yes I was considering the same. But the data (psl-xx-x) is entered by a barcode scanner, so the data have to be split from scan.

Comment: Hmm fair enough, You could split on insert, but I don't know if the different parts have specific identifying parts or not. rishipuri's answer will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`substring_index`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) is your friend

```
SELECT substring_index(substring_index(value, '-', 2), '-', -1) FROM data;
```

[SQLFiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64a86fd/7)

Comment: Wonderful! I can't believe you solved it so fast. Thanks mate!